# Алгоритм Гомори-Ху

Tags: алгоритм

Объясните, пожалуйста, или дайте какие-то источники, где можно найти объяснение алгоритма построения дерева Гомори-Ху. В русскоязычном интернете вопрос актуален с 2005 года

Comment: [2 ссылка в поисковике](https://ru.qwe.wiki/wiki/Gomory–Hu_tree)

Comment: Я всего лишь первокурсник, для меня это набор иероглифов :)

Comment: Почему вас задали тогда это?